# What happened to the Teradata Kylo product?

Tags: teradata, kylo

- GitHub activity is just [empty last month](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/pulse), at least
- download links for the [latest release 0.10.1](https://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.0/about/Downloads.html#kylo-distribution-0-10-1) (March, 2019) lead to nowhere
- same thing for [VirtualBox images](https://kylo.io/quickstart.html) - AWS S3 bucket does not exist

My questions are:

- Is the project dead?
- Is there any open source active project which supersedes Kylo?

Comment: According to the post pinned at the top of the [Kylo community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kylo-community) Google Group, Teradata decided to discontinue Kylo development and support in early 2019 and no new sponsor stepped forward to take over the project.

Comment: @Fred, if you do not mind put your comment as an answer and I will accept it. This is the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the post pinned at the top of the [Kylo community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kylo-community) Google Group, Teradata decided to discontinue Kylo development and support in early 2019 and no new sponsor stepped forward to take over the project

Answer (score 1):

Here is the message posted in the Kylo Google Group:

> Google Groups State of Kylo project matt.hutton
>
> Feb 12, 2020 4:18 PM
>
> Posted in group: Kylo Community
>
> Teradata made the decision to discontinue Kylo in early 2019. Teradata
> had been the sole sponsor of the open-source project and offered paid
> corporate training, consulting services, and enterprise subscriptions
> for support. The team was unable to immediately secure a new sponsor
> and devs have moved on to other projects.
>
> The last official release of Kylo was March 2019.  The downloads of
> the RPM and sandbox are no longer available but you may still build
> the RPM (or TAR) from maven.